# Linux Bash - Calling a function returns a "No such file or directory" error

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a small program in Bash that looks up the IP address's of websites in 3 ways. Everything else works except the 3rd method:

The user passes a filename into the code as the first parameter - in this case the file is "domains.txt" and contains 3 test domains.

**Edit 2: I added a much more concise code that only produces the error. Edited the post a bit to reflect that change. Old code copy/paste was removed.**

```
#!/bin/bash
function Domain_Lookup_Func {
filename=$1
while read -r line
do
echo "$line" | nslookup
done < "$filename"
}

initialInput=$1
fileChk=".txt"
if [[ $initialInput == *"$fileChk"* ]]; then
Domain_Lookup_Func
fi
```

This is a code exercise for University, and this is my first experience with Bash in particular, so I understand this is some painfully basic code. I do however have coding experience so technical explanation is not lost on me (hopefully).

I have spent hours trying to fix this and I've tried what feels like dozens of different ways to check for substrings - nothing works and other questions I've found relating to this issue either have solutions that don't work or aren't in the same context so the answers aren't relevant. Every other part of this code works perfectly except that single substring check - including the while loop.

I have found some information that indicates the code is interpreted differently if I use "bash (filename).sh" to open it in terminal, or have "#!/bin/bash" at the top of my code. This may be the issue, but to be honest I have no idea what that means for my code.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not necessary to have *all* that code in the example. I suggest a round of [machete debugging](https://rootdirectory.de/doku.php?id=software:machetedebugging) to come up with a [mcve]...

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you. I'll leave the entire code block up for now and edit when I've cut it down. I personally thought sharing the entire code would be more helpful than not. Just the first function and if statement should suffice for testing.

Comment: Inside a function `$1` refers to the first of arguments the function is called with. You're calling `Domain_Lookup_Func` with no arguments and `filename` ends up empty. Try `Domain_Lookup_Func "$initialInput"`.

Comment: I think @oguz is the correct answer (You should post it below). You should also make sure that the file is in the same working directory as the script.

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you so much! This fixed the problem and the code now works. 
In hindsight it was such a simple oversight, but that seems to be how coding works.

Comment: BTW, in `echo "$line" | nslookup` -- are you sure nslookup reads from stdin at all, vs expecting the hostname to be passed as a command line? I would expect the command to need to be `nslookup "$line"`. That said, the whole loop could probably be replaced with `xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 nslookup <"$filename"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will be honest, I don't know. As stated, this is my first experience with Bash. I only done it this way to ensure the file contents (google.com etc) were properly piped into the nslookup. 

It works as it is, and considering my circumstances with this uni assignment (I need to redo this code in DOS and some other research stuff) I'm leaving the 'making it fancy and neat' part until last, where I might have extra time. 

Could you explain the 'xargs' example you gave? (If that sort of discussion isn't allowed here then no worries!)

Comment: xargs reads content from stdin and moves it to command line arguments. _By default_ it performs roughly shell-like parsing of input (trying to honor quotes/backslashes/etc), but when either `-0` is used to split on NULs or `-d` is used to specify a different delimiter, it skips that parsing and _only_ splits on the desired character. `-n 1` tells it to only put one hostname on each nslookup command's arguments -- that might be unnecessary, but since I didn't check the nslookup manual it seemed prudent.

Comment: (BTW, in general, nslookup is somewhat antiquated; a more modern equivalent would be `dig +short`)

Answer (score 0):

@oguzismail has the correct answer in their comment (you need to pass arguments to a function if you intend to use position variables like `$1`, etc), but I wanted to suggest some things you could do to debug this sort of thing in the future. If you run your script with tracing enabled (`-x`), you will see:

```
$ bash -x thescript.sh hostnames.txt
+ initialInput=hostnames.txt
+ fileChk=.txt
+ [[ names.txt == *.txt* ]]
+ Domain_Lookup_Func
+ filename=
lookup.sh: line 3: : No such file or directory
```

That shows clearly that `$1` inside the function is evaluating to the empty string. In fact, the error message was already providing that clue; if you attempt to redirect input form a nonexistent file, bash includes the filename in the error:

```
$ cat < filethatdoesnotexist.txt
-bash: filethatdoesnotexist.txt: No such file or directory
```

In the error message you see, the spot normally occupied by the filename is blank, which is why you see `line 3: : ...`.